# Scala plug-in for Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, java-8, eclipse-luna

Do I understand correctly that the only version of `Scala IDE` compatible with Eclipse Luna is [`Scala IDE 4.0.0 Milestone 3`](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala-ide-400-milestone-2)?

I'm not familiar with this `Milestone` terminology.  It seems to be something between stable version and nightly builds. Is it the same as Release Candidate?  In old *waterfall* terminology would it be *alpha* or *beta*?

In other words: How safe is it?

If I already have `Eclipse Luna` and `JDK 1.8`, and want `Scala` support, do I really have a choice?

If someone already uses this combination, please share your experience.

---

And what is *really* confusing is that when I open `Marketplace` in Luna it offers `3.0x` version.

[image: Eclipse Marketplace]

Go figure...

Comment: I find the Google Groups to be more responsive that SO to general Scala-IDE questions:  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-ide-user

Comment: I can't get even Milestone 3 to work in Luna. The nightlies do, though (although that means I can't use the worksheet)

Comment: You can install a nightly version of the Worksheet from [here](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet#download). Choose the one for 4.0.x-2.11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `4.0 M3` is the minimum version that supports Luna. The upcoming versions will support Luna as well, but there are no plans to support older version of the Scala IDE on Luna.

Therefore, if you don't want to build an older version of Scala IDE, where you successfully included Luna support, there is no other way than to use `4.0M3+`.

Milestones generally are equivalent to beta level I would say. M3 is the version before RC1 and RCs are not far away from final versions.

The milestones should be safe, even the nightlies are because they are already used to develop new versions of the IDE, but especially the nightlies could be broken for some days. For milestones it is more realistic that new features can be broken, but features that worked already in an older final version should be very safe.

The marketspace only offers the final version, if you want a milestone/nightly/RC you need to download it from the Scala IDE homepage.

Answer (score 3):

Not really addressing the issue here, but I will anyways add an answer for people who wants to install Scala IDE(stable version) in Eclipse Luna.

Instead of going to marketplaces, go to

`help -> Install new software`

copy the version you want to install from

http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html

and paste it in the dialog box in Eclipse , press ADD.
It will list down the options,

select `Scala IDE for Eclipse` and finish.

Scala IDE will be  installed in eclipse luna!

Comment: Your link points to the page with Scala 3.x versions, which are clearly marked to be for "**Eclipse 3.8-4.3 (Juno and Kepler)**". For **Luna (4.4)** you need Scala plugin version 4.0.  Were you personally successful in following your instructions?

Comment: Sorry. There was a slight mistake. We need to download Nightly builds. This link will work http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html
Let me edit it :)